# How to apply client side password encryption in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, encryption

In my registration form I am sending username and password from signup form to my controller and storing after password encryption.

In think I should first encrypt password at client side and then send to my controller(server side)so that my data is secure from packet capturing.

Now I am looking for your idea or guidance for any available feature for this if any.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You would want your server to have an ssl certificate installed and make sure the client makes requests using https.

Comment: In theory you can encrypt the password by public key, send to the server, and then decrypt with the private key. But that is weird to implement this yourself when HTTPS can make all traffic encrypted.

Comment: Thank for your thought, I am in my developing mode now , before going production I will use ssl certificate and go with https.

Comment: Use HTTPS, don't try to implement [client-side Javascript cryptography](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Yes I am going to use HTTPS in production mode, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) is for :)

Comment: Is there no other way without https ?

Comment: Any other implementation is going to have to work just like HTTPS - you'd need to negotiate a key using some form of public-key mechanism.

Comment: @SonuR Is there any reason why you can't use HTTPS?

Comment: Actually my site is on development mode, so I just thought about this, But now its clear concept, to use HTTPS. and Its ok till I am in development mode.

Comment: That's not totally true! With SSLStrip, you have no warning and with a man and the middle attack you can see passwords in clear. See : http://paladion.net/ssl-stripping-revisiting-http-downgrading-attacks/

Answer (score 0):

While you can encrypt data client-side; it offers virtually no protection as man-in-the-middle attacks can still occur before the data is encrypted, which would leak the data to the attacker regardless.

Your best option is to get an SSL cert. You don't have to get a professional / paid one; a self-signed one will do just fine if you have a small / personal website.  Encrypting data client-side will only give a false sense of security.

Comment: Not totally true. See : http://paladion.net/ssl-stripping-revisiting-http-downgrading-attacks/